# Creating and stopping threads in JavaFX

Tags: java, multithreading, javafx, task

I have a task to work with threads and JavaFX library. A separate thread 1 need to be started by pressing a button. The thread is supposed to fulfill a list with Integer values (100 - 150) with a small interval (e.g. 5 ms).

And after values are generated, it should stop. A new thread 2 must start and fill a ViewList with generated values.

But I get an exception each time when a new value is added to my list by thread 1:

```
Exception in thread "Thread-4" java.lang.IllegalStateException: Not on FX application thread; currentThread = Thread-4
    at com.sun.javafx.tk.Toolkit.checkFxUserThread(Toolkit.java:204)
    at com.sun.javafx.tk.quantum.QuantumToolkit.checkFxUserThread(QuantumToolkit.java:364)
    at javafx.scene.Scene.addToDirtyList(Scene.java:485)
    at javafx.scene.Node.addToSceneDirtyList(Node.java:424)
    at javafx.scene.Node.impl_markDirty(Node.java:415)
```

I tried to use `Platform.runLater()` in button event listener instead of creating a new Thread, but the program stops responding in that case.

Could anyone please help me, how to fill a collection with values in a separate thread and how to start a second one to update ViewList element after the first thread finishes?

Here is my class:

```
int itemName = 100;
Button btnOne = new Button("Button one");
Label label = new Label("Press the button to start");

ObservableList<String> listOptions = FXCollections.observableArrayList();
ListView<String> list;

@Override
public void start(Stage primaryStage) throws Exception{
    primaryStage.setTitle("Hurry");

    list = new ListView<>(listOptions);
    list.setPrefSize(120, 120);

    MultipleSelectionModel<String> lvSelModel =
            list.getSelectionModel();

    FlowPane rootNode = new FlowPane(10, 10);
    rootNode.setAlignment(Pos.CENTER);

    Scene myScene = new Scene(rootNode, 180, 200);
    primaryStage.setScene(myScene);

    lvSelModel.selectedItemProperty().addListener(
        (changed, oldValue, newValue) -> {
        label.setText("List option selected: " + newValue);
    });

    rootNode.getChildren().addAll(btnOne, list, label);
    primaryStage.show();

    Task<Integer> threadOne = new Task<Integer>(){
        @Override
        protected Integer call() throws Exception{

          while(itemName < 130){
                final int finalValue = itemName++;
                listOptions.add(String.valueOf(itemName));
                Platform.runLater(
                () ->  label.setText("Generating: " + finalValue));
                Thread.sleep(100);
            }
            label.setText("Thread 1 finished");
            return itemName;
        }
    };

    btnOne.setOnAction( 
        ae -> {
        Thread th = new Thread(threadOne);
        th.setDaemon(true);
        th.start();
    });

}

public static void main(String[] args) {
    launch(args);
}}`
```

The result program should be like this:

[image]

Thanks everyone for your time!

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Since `listOptions` is the list of items in the list view, calling `listOptions.add(...)` modifies the UI (the list view). Thus it needs to be executed on the FX Application Thread, similarly to setting the text of the label. Just move that line in side the `Platform.runLater(...)`:

```
Task<Integer> threadOne = new Task<Integer>(){
    @Override
    protected Integer call() throws Exception{

      while(itemName < 130){
            final int finalValue = itemName++;
            Platform.runLater(() ->  {
                listOptions.add(String.valueOf(itemName));
                label.setText("Generating: " + finalValue);
            });
            Thread.sleep(100);
        }
        label.setText("Thread 1 finished");
        return itemName;
    }
};
```

To start another task (or, indeed, do anything) when the first task finishes, use the task's `onSucceeded` handler:

```
threadOne.setOnSucceeded(e -> {
    // create another task and run it in another thread...
});
```

Comment: Thank you!! You helped a lot!